# How do I remove all traces of a file from Subversion?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to remove a file, with all version history, from SVN? For instance if you add a file with confidential financial information simply to have it backed up, and then realise it's in a SVN sub-directory all your developers can see...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but it's not easy. You must be an administrator on the server where the Subversion server is running. Then use `svnadmin dump` to dump the repository, and `svndumpfilter` to exclude the appropriate file, and then reconstitute the repository. This is a costly and expensive operation which will take a long time for large repositories.

See **[the Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal)** for more details. **[A detailed example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering)** of how to do this is also given in the Subversion book.

Comment: A good fail-safe against this is to prevent the committing of code which would cause these sorts of problematic issues -- for instance, as a first pass, you could have a whitelist of file extensions that your pre-commit hook will check for.

Comment: Fail safe wouldn't have helped here. We have a documentation section, with Word Files. I created one there with the plan of the next phase - timelines, costs, everything, and committed it to take a backup :(

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, this is going to require dumping and filtering. However there a few gotchas here which can make it painful (i.e. if the file has moved or paths changed). I just went through a very similar process and documented it carefully here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/12/black-art-of-splitting-subversion.html